# What happens in C++ if you pass an anonymous object into a function that takes a reference?

Tags: c++, reference

IE what happens if you have this following piece of code?

```
int mean(const vector<int> & data) {
  int res = 0;
  for(size_t i = 0; i< data.size(); i++) {
    res += data[i];
  }
  return res/data.size();
}

vector<int> makeRandomData() {
  vector<int> stuff;
  int numInts = rand()%100;
  for(int i = 0; i< numInts; i++) {
    stuff.push_back(rand()%100);
  }
}

void someRandomFunction() {
  int results = mean(makeRandomData());
}
```

Am I correct in thinking that C++ will just preserve the newly created object for the life of mean, and then destroy it afterwards since it goes out of scope?

Also, how does this work/interfere with RVO?

Thanks in advance.

EDITED: Added const, forgot to put that in.

Comment: You are missing the return statement in makeRandomData. (I just mention this in case someone gets confused by this.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My psychic powers tell me that you're compiling this on Visual C++, which is why it even works. In standard C++, you cannot pass an rvalue (which is what the return value of `makeRandomData` is) to a reference-to-non-const, so the question is moot.

However, the question is still valid if you change the signature of `mean` to take a `const vector<int>&`. In which case it all boils down to the lifetime of the temporary - which is defined to last until the end of the "full expression" in which it occurs. In your particular case, the full expression is the entire initializer of `results`. In case of an expression statement, the full expression is that entire statement.

The Standard does not specify any way in which function arguments can inhibit RVO, but, of course, RVO is a mandate to the compiler to do a particular optimization regardless of visible side effects, not a *requirement* to do it. When (and if) RVO happens is entirely up to the specific compiler you're using. That said, there does not seem to be any reason why it should be affected by this in any way.

Comment: Aha, quirkiness. Thanks for clearing that up a bit. I was indeed doing this in VS, but I forgot to mention the vector was const as well.

So to clear things up, if the signature was indeed const, what would be the observable differences between doing this and just passing by value normally? Thanks

Comment: @Pavel Minaev: I didn't quiet get the 'mandate' vs 'requirement' for the compiler for RVO

Comment: @Xzhsh: the difference would be one extra copy of the vector (the one that it would otherwise have to make for the argument). As written, with references, it will make at most one copy when returning it, and might use NRVO to avoid copying at all, constructing directly into a temporary.

Comment: @chubsdad: the Standard _permits_ the compilers to do RVO (despite the potentially observable side effect of copy ctors & dtors for that extra copy), but does not _require_ them to.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ you can't pass a temporary object to a function that takes a non-constant reference. The example you posted above will not compile. If your compiler compiles it, it is a quirk (extension) of your compiler. If your compiler compiles it without even issuing a diagnostic message, your compiler is broken.

A temporary object (result of your `makeRandomData()` call), can only be passed to `mean` through a const-qualified reference. I.e. your `mean` has to be declared as

```
int mean(const vector<int> & data)
```

in which case the reference will be bound either directly to the temporary object returned by `makeRandomData()`, or to another copy of that temporary object the compiler might choose to create. (The latter is unlikely in this case, but might happen in theory.)